# tensorflow vs keras execution

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I use this code to build a regression model

```
training_input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn( x=x_train,
                                                  y=y_train['Price'],
                                                  batch_size=256,
                                                  num_epochs=500,
                                                  shuffle=True )
regressor = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(feature_columns = feature_cols, 
                                          activation_fn = tf.nn.relu,
                                          hidden_units=[100, 50, 100],
                                          model_dir = 'model',
                                          optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer( learning_rate= 0.01 ))
regressor.train(input_fn = training_input_func, steps=2000)
```

It takes 2-3 min to execute, But when i try this code using keras

```
epochs = 500
batch_size = 256
model_1 = keras.Sequential()
model_1.add(Dense(100, activation ="tanh"))
model_1.add(Dense(50, activation ="relu"))
model_1.add(Dense(y_train_array.shape[0]))
model_1.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=Adam(), metrics=[metrics.mae])
model_1.fit(x_train_array, y_train_array,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        epochs=epochs,
        shuffle=True,
        verbose=2, # Change it to 2, if wished to observe execution.  o if not
        validation_data=(x_validation_array, y_validation_array),
        callbacks=keras_callbacks,
        use_multiprocessing=True,
        workers=50)
```

It takes almost 3-4 hour for first epoch. The size of training example is around 3M and validation is 30 k. Is there any problem in my code? I know keras take more time time compare to tensorflow.

Comment: Is difference in batch size intentional? There is a huge difference between 10 and 256 batch size. You also missed model.fit call for keras in your question.

Comment: edit the question.